# Where does MapInfo store its Coordinate Systems?

Tags: mapinfo

When choosing a projection in MapInfo, there is a large list of available coordinate systems. Where is the file that stores these and is it easily editable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MapInfo uses a file called MAPINFOW.PRJ to store all its projections.  It IS easily editable.  Search under program files MapInfo/Professional (from memory) for this file.  It's not encrypted or subject to any security, so there's no withcraft needed to make changes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I take a back up first though, obviously!

Comment: Nah, if you're going to be a bear, be a grizzly ;)

Answer (score 1):

For others who need to know the format - it is in MapInfo Pro User Guide. For your reference just the relevant chapter: https://www.scribd.com/doc/265737649/MapInfoProUserGuide-Projections-chapter

Comment: That's the User Guide for MapInfo Pro 12.5. Do note that we add new datums etc. in most new versions of MapInfo Pro. I would therefor recommend that you have a look at the User Guide for the version of MapInfo Pro that you currently are using. They can be found here (at least the latest versions): http://www.pbinsight.com/support/product-documentation/details/mapinfo-professional